# How to always show dates instead of pound signs when Excel columns are too small?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2016

Excel shows pound signs (#) for date cells when the column is too narrow.  I understand I can resize/autofit the column or change its formatting.  I'm a developer and I open lots of csv files containing several date/time columns and it is tedious to do this by hand every time. How can I disable this behavior permanently?  I want it to simply treat these columns as other text columns... show as much of the value as possible.

Answer (score 0):

If your cvs files have a certain display format, you can use Macros to make it automatically do the events you want on each time you open them. For instance, let's say that the first column of each cvs is time, and the second column is date. then you can record a macro to reformat the first two columns to the correct cell format. Then, make that macro available to all workbooks.

If you want to auto-fit the contents by default, then you will have to create an Excel add-in to make it possible. take a look at [this thread](http://www.excelforum.com/excel-general/397057-autofit-by-default.html) will be helpful for you.

Answer (score 0):

There is a formatting option in the usual Excel cell formatting dialog. Second tab:  Alignment.

The middle region of that tab is called `Text control` and has three option. Click to activate the second of them:  `Shrink to fit`.

Excel will now always adjust the size of the cell's font to fully display a single full line of data that is entered in the cell with the caveat that multi-line displays (for instance, using Wrap Text or character 10 (`Alt-Enter`) to force division into lines) usually will not display as desired. That makes some sense if you think about it, at least the Wrap Text situation.

Of course, the font is smaller and maybe you really mean "display the full result instead of pound signs AND maintain the full size of the formatted font" in which case, this won't do you any good. Nothing will in that case, but there it is.